# Raspberry pi をアナログ電話として使う方法の選択肢

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry piを家の固定電話端子に繋ぎ、プログラマブルなアナログ電話として使うには、どんな方法がありますか。

Twilio、GoogleVoiceなどの外部サービスを利用したり、VoIPアダプタを使ってIP電話として使うのではなく、純粋にそれ自体をアナログ電話として発着信と音声のやり取りをする方法があれば知りたいです。
　ボイスモデムを買って繋いで試してもみたのですが、ATコマンドで発着信ができるものの、ボイスモデムではアナログ音声のやり取りができないようです。

お詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたら、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

VoIP ルーターまたはVoIPゲートウェイとラズパイを接続すればできると思います。
以下が参考になるのではないでしょうか。
https://www.voip-info.jp/index.php/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E5%9B%9E%E7%B7%9A%E3%81%AE%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A

公衆電話回線に自作機器を接続することは、法律上できない(技適)ので、電話回線-IP変換する何らかの機器を経由する必要があります。