# Raspberry Pi をアナログ固定回線と接続したい

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi にアナログ電話としての機能を持たせ、自動的に電話をかけ通話を行う仕組みを作りたいと思っております。
関連した資料や参考になりそうなURLなどあればどなたかご教示いただけますでしょうか。
もちろん技適に関しては実現次第取得しようと考えております。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 重複候補 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/32242

Comment: 既に売ってないようですが、こんな製品 [ARDUINO DIAL UP MODEM SHIELD](https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?t=36130), [Multi-Function PSTN Dial Up Modem Module WP130X](https://www.tindie.com/products/annajna/multi-function-pstn-dial-up-modem-module-wp130x/) があり、ここ [Modem Chip](https://www.arrow.com/en/categories/communication/modems/modem-chip) にリストされているようなモデムチップを使って同様のものを作ってみては？

Answer (score 1):

ラズパイに、ボイスモデムをつなげればいいというはなしとなります
まあ、そいつのラズパイ向けのドライバを用意できるかがポイントになりそうですが。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ボイスモデムなるもの初めて知りました。いくつかサイトを見ましたが、今はあまり売っていないのですね（もしくは高め）。

Answer (score 1):

アナログモデム（モデム・ターミナルアダプタ）　というインターフェースがまだ入手できると思います。
ATコマンドで発信ができます。

Answer (score 0):

市販されているアナログ電話機（プッシュホン等）のボタン部分の接点をRaspberry Piからたたくようにすればいいんじゃないですか？
リレーを使うのが簡単だと思いますが。
音声を通したいのであればAD,DAすればいいと思うので、まずは市販されている電話機の回路を調べるのがいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

[Asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/) を使えば無料でデジタル構内電話交換機(PBX)が構築できます、他にハードとしては Grandstream辺りの VoIPアダプタが必要になりますが現行の HT802 でも Amazonで一万円しません。
国内での情報は [VoIP-Info.jp Wiki](http://voip-info.jp/) ほか、解説、まとめサイトや Raspberry Pi での作例もいくつか公開されてます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。私のやりたいことは、あくまで一般家庭のアナログ電話回線を利用した仕組みでして、Internetを使わないものなんです。

Comment: VoIPアダプタ(VoIPゲートウェイ)を使えば NTTのダイヤル回線かトーン回線(及び同種のアナログ回線)で運用できます。宅内の Raspberry Pi, PCやタブレット等を電話の子機として発呼も着呼も可能です、宅内のインターホンとしても使えます。ほか通話記録、留守番電話や通話の録音も設定により可能です。目覚ましとしても使えますね。Internetはソフトウエアのインストール段階まではあった方が楽ですが、USBメモリなど代替手段を利用できると思います。